# Biber installed via tlmgr, but not found on command

Tags: biber, tlmgr, tinytex

On Ubuntu 22.04, I have installed TexLive (actually, [TinyTeX](https://yihui.org/tinytex/)) and have installed biber and biblatex packages. Command `tlmgr info biber` returns

```
package:     biber
category:    Package
shortdesc:   A BibTeX replacement for users of BibLaTeX
longdesc:    Biber is a BibTeX replacement for users of BibLaTeX. Biber supports full UTF-8, can (re)-encode input and output, supports highly configurable sorting, dynamic bibliography sets and many other features. The CTAN distribution offers a compressed tar archive of the sources, etc., together with "binary" distributions for a variety of platforms. Note: on SourceForge biber is formally named "biblatex-biber", to distinguish it from an earlier (now apparently moribund) project called "biber".
installed:   Yes
revision:    66455
sizes:       bin: 29329k
relocatable: No
cat-version: 2.19
cat-license: artistic2
cat-topics:  biblio
cat-related: bibtex crosstex biblatex
cat-contact-home: http://biblatex-biber.sourceforge.net/
cat-contact-repository: https://github.com/plk/biber
cat-contact-bugs: https://github.com/plk/biber/issues
collection:  collection-bibtexextra
```

And yet, it seems biber is not actually installed. Command `biber --help` returns

```
Command 'biber' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install biber
```

Attempt to compile a tex file results in an error with the message containing

```
Latexmk: applying rule 'biber main'...
Rule 'biber main':  Reasons for rerun
Category 'other':
  Rerun of 'biber main' forced or previously required

------------
Run number 1 of rule 'biber main'
------------
------------
Running 'biber  "main.bcf"'
------------
sh: 1: biber: not found
```

I've also attempted to install biber through apt. This resulted in version 2.18, which is incompatible with the biblatex version installed via tlmgr.

I would appreciate any suggestions on why this might be happening and/or how I could resolve the issue.

Comment: what is your path?

Comment: What a gazpacho! Use apt only to remove any texlive  package. Tinytex  executable files  should be   `~/.TinyTeX/bin` or so, and if you what access to an executable in that directory, you must provide the full path or make that path searchable.

Comment: Thank you for the comments! Indeed, there is `biber` in the directory `~/.TinyTeX/bin/x86_64-linux`. I have added it to the PATH. This has not resolved the issue, and the command `biber` is still not found. Whereas, for example, the command `bibtex` also found in TinyTeX directory is recognized (both in and out of the directory).